# How to define a clojurescript function in the javascript global namespace at compile time?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I'm looking for a way to define Clojurescript functions in the Javascript global namespace at compile time. What I mean by compile-time is that I want the Clojurescript compiler to output this: `function some_fn() { }`. I know that this is not idiomatic and everything should reside in a namespace but the environment that I'm in forces me to do this. So, ideally something like `(defn ^:global some-fn [])` that would work similar to how `:export` works but ignores the namespace.

I'm aware of the runtime method for defining global functions using goog.global, e.g
`(set! goog.global.someFunction some-clojure-fn)` but this doesn't work in my environment.

Comment: Are you aware that if you annotate your function with `^:export` you can refer to it directly from javascript? e.g. `my.name.space.some_fn()`

Comment: Yes I am. I'm afraid that I really want it to be a top level function because I can't deal with the name.space.prefix stuff.

Comment: Kanaka's answer is what you're after then. Window is where top-level stuff lives.

Comment: some javascript environments don't provide any sort of global object, which means we need to generate `var foo = "bar"` - is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you could define it in a namespace and then expose it in the window (or GLOBAL or this depending on your environment) object:

```
(defn foo [x] (* 2 x))
(aset js/window "foo" myns/foo)  ;; where myns is where foo is defined
```

You should then be able to call `foo` from the window (which is the global JavaScript namespace in the browser).

**Update**: As suggested by @TerjeNorderhaug, you can set a variable in the global namespace like this:

```
(set! js/foo foo)
```

Comment: Alternatively set the global with `(set! js/foo foo)`

Answer (score 2):

**Setting a javascript var to an anonymous Clojurescript function** will define the compiled function in the Javascript global namespace:

`(set! js/some_fn (fn []))`

Calling the function works as expected:

`(js/some_fn)`